# How to solve GDI Memory Leak in Panel paint event

Tags: c#, forms, window, gdi

I draw rectangle in panel using timer is interval 1 sec.
but I confirm when timer is running, memory leaks is occured.

My code is below

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using(SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
            {
                var xRowCount = m_nEA / m_nX;
                var xColumnCount = m_nEA % m_nX;

                if (xRowCount > 0)
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, CellY * xRowCount));
                }
                if (xColumnCount > 0)
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, CellY * xRowCount, CellX * xColumnCount, CellY));
                }
                if (CellY * xRowCount < label1.Location.Y)
                {
                    label1.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
                double p = ((double)m_nEA / (double)m_nTotal) * 100.0;
                string pct = string.Format("{0:F2}" + "%", p);
                label1.Text = string.Format("Total Count : {0} / {1}\r\n{2}", m_nEA, m_nTotal, pct);
            }
            e.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I doubt you should dispose the EventArgs, since they also will be used by other subscribers of the event -- however, this probably should only cause exceptions, not memleaks. (see Form1_Paint in the first example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs(v=vs.110).aspx )

Comment: Can you describe how long you let your program run, and how much memory it has after some seconds and some minutes/hours? Did you try to explicitly call the Garbage Collector or did Windows notify you that there is too few memory left?

Comment: @phi1010 Calling garbage collection increases slightly, but then memory is retained. I don't know my way is right

Comment: Explain how you “confirm ... memory leaks is occured”. Note that using Task Manager for this [is not accurate](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f7bf6c39-139c-4027-8f0d-78b42d6512ff/memory-leak?forum=clr).

Comment: @DourHighArch I checked Task Manager. If you have best way to check Memory Leak, please let me know

Comment: You have to use a memory profiler; examples are given in the link I provided.